# how to update multiple records for single user in database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to update multiple roles for user when admin update user roles

I have table as follow

**user_roles**

```
   username || role_name

   user1 | role1
   user2 | role2
```

**users**

```
   username || password

   user1 | abc
```

now suppose admin updates `username` to `guest` as well as assign `multiple roles` lets say 5 `roles(role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)` then how to update table ?

do I need to first delete existing records from both tables ?

Comment: Look into `normalizing` your tables.  Probably better to use an `ID` as your `primary key` in your `users table` and then associate the id in the `user_roles` table, thus no worry to change.

Comment: i have set username as primary key in users table

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete existing records, you can simply use a SQL Update statement, see the below link for how it's done.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp